# can anyone tell me how to install magento version 2.4.0? what to do next from here

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.4.0

I am trying to install Magento version 2.4.0 in my localhost by running URL in the browser directly.

Can anyone tell me how can i install it?

What to do next from here.

Please help me to solve this issue.

I tried my best but it did not install so far.

[image: Magento2.4.0]

Answer (score 1):

From Magento version 2.4.0, you can not install Magento using URL. you have to use Command Line Interface for this.

Also, MySql has been replaced with Elastic Search for catalog search so you have to install Elastic Search in your localhost first.

Check this link for System Requirements: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

If you have already installed Elastic Search in your localhost then you can run below command from root directory of your project in terminal

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento240/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento240 --db-user=root --db-password=mysql123 \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_GB \
--currency=GBP --timezone=Europe/London --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1 \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

You can also use `--disable-modules=Magento_TwoFactorAuth` argument in the command to disable the Two Factor Auth module because by default Magento use Two Factor Authentication for admin login.

You can disable it from `app/etc/config.php` later after installing magento by changing value from **1** to **0** for `Magento_TwoFactorAuth`

Then run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```